# Variadic templates and functions overriding

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, variadic-templates, overriding

I want to use variadic templates in order to do such calls:

```
make_set<int, double, int>("...");
```

Basically the idea is to call recursively `read_row()` function as long as there is at least one argument.

Here are overridden functions:

```
template <typename __First>
void read_row(Row r){}

template <typename __First, typename... __Args>
void read_row(Row r)
{
    int index = r.size() - sizeof...(__Args);
    auto value = r.getValue<__First>(index);
    read_row<__Args...>(r);
}

template <typename... __Args>
void make_set(const char* fileName="")
{
    Parser parser(fileName);

    for(int i = 0; i < parser.rowCount(); ++i)
    {
        auto row = parser.getRow(i);
        read_row<__Args...>(row);
    }
}
```

But the compiler insists that the recursive call is ambiguous.

```
/Users/kirill/Desktop/TSP-EQ/TSP-EQ/tspeq/tspset/tspset.hpp:42:13: Call to 'read_row' is ambiguous
```

Comment: Identifiers starting with double underscore are reserved for the implementation. Technically this is undefined behavior. Please make a [mcve] because right now you are not showing enough to reproduce the error. Also please copy/paste the error message from your compiler instead of posting pictures of your IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ambiguous because

```
template <typename __First>
```

ask for exactly one template type parameter and

```
template <typename __First, typename... __Args>
```

ask for one or more template type parameters.

All goes well with two or more parameters (the second one is choose), but when the function is called with only one parameter?

A possible way to solve the problem is impose two or more parameters in the second one version. Something like

```
template <typename F>
void read_row (Row r)
 {
   // auto value = r.getValue<F>(r.size()); ???
 }

template <typename F, typename S, typename... As>
void read_row (Row r)
 {
   int index = r.size() - (1U + sizeof...(As));
   auto value = r.getValue<F>(index);
   read_row<S, As...>(r);
 }
```

Comment: I implied that function as a recursion base

Comment: @KirillKorolev - sure, you need a ground case; but tou have to write it unambiguous; answer improved to give an example.

Comment: @KirillKorolev That's the problem. You implied. You didn't write code understandable by a compiler, so people interpret it some way which leads to misunderstandings. Avoid those by providing a proper test case.